# Divergence of $\frac{1}{a_{1}^{s}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}^{s}}+\frac{1}{a_{3}^{s}}....$

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Assume that we know this converges. $$\frac{1}{a_{1}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}}+\frac{1}{a_{3}}+....$$

Is it possible to detect for which largest $0<s<1$ the sum below diverges?

$$\frac{1}{a_{1}^{s}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}^{s}}+\frac{1}{a_{3}^{s}}....$$

I was thinking about Riemann zeta function and i came up with this question. As you know for $t>1$, $\zeta (t)$ is convergent but $\zeta (1)$ is divergent.

$a_{1},a_{2},....,s$ are positive real numbers.

Sorry for my terrible English!

Comment: You might as well phrase it like this: Given that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{a_{i}^{-1}}$ converges, how can we find the largest real number $0<s<1$, for which $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{a_{i}^{-s}}$ converges... BTW, I think you actually want the smallest $s$.

Comment: If $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}^{-s}$ is divergent and $0<t<s$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}^{-t}$ is going to be divergent to. So i think largest 0<s<1 is the right question?

Comment: It converges for $s=1$ and diverges for $s=0$. So the largest $s$ for which it converges may be $0.9$... No, wait, $0.99$... No, wait, $0.999$... I hope you understand my point by now. For every $s<1$, there is a larger $s'<1$. And if it converges for $s$, then it most certainly converges for $s'$. The smallest $s$ for which it converges, on the other hand, is a value that could be determined "unquestionably", unless it converges for all $0<s<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the convergent series
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{n(\log n)^2},
$$
however
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{n^s(\log n)^{2s}},
$$
is divergent for all $s\in (0,1)$.